# how do you get ubuntu for android via windows 7

Tags: installation, windows-7, ubuntu-touch, windows-8

I personally think that ubuntu touch is a great idea, but there is a problem with it: **As far as I can tell, Ubuntu for Android can't be installed unless you have ubuntu on a computer. And my PC runs Microsoft Windows.** I've tried the commands that are listed on the site, and nothing has happened. So someone please explain how to get ubuntu for android via Windows 7/8.

Comment: Use a custom recovery on the phone an flash the daily images directly on it http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/daily-preinstalled/current/ but touch is in development and ment for *Ubuntu* developers so...

Answer (score 1):

You do, indeed, need to install Touch into Ubuntu. You have two choices:

Make your PC a [dual boot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) with both Windows 8 and Ubuntu, leaving Windows 8 intact but shrinking the space on the hard drive/SSD it uses and [give some space to Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-removing-windows), around [8GB or so](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140070/formatting-hard-drive-before-installing-ubuntu/140084#140084). The process is pretty painless and menu-driven, and you can resize things later without needing to reinstall either Windows or Ubuntu.

Set up [virtualization](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330803/ubuntu-32-bit-or-64-bit-on-windows-virtual-pc-on-64-bit-windows-8) in the Windows operating system, then install Ubuntu as a [virtual machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine), and Touch inside the Ubuntu virtual machine. This is more difficult.

Comment: Or just **LiveCD** 'try it' install, and run **Ubuntu** *from within* **Windows 7**.